# Split string with split_part in Asian language

Tags: sql, postgresql, split, southeast-asian-languages

I have a column with Asian addresses. I want to extract the substring until the first whitespace. However, this does not work here. My suspicion is that it has to do with the Asian language, but I do not why nor how to deal with this issue.

That's the code:

```
select address, split_part(address, ' ', 1) from asian
```

Exemplary output (no splitting has happened!). As you can see there are spaces.

```
address
"千葉県富津市新富２０−１　新日本製鐵株式会社　技術開発本部内"
split_part
"千葉県富津市新富２０−１　新日本製鐵株式会社　技術開発本部内"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can hack [ideographic space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3000/index.htm) with `chr()`, eg:

```
t=# select split_part('千葉県富津市新富２０−１　新日本製鐵株式会社　技術開発本部内',chr(12288),1);
       split_part
-------------------------
 千葉県富津市新富２０−１
(1 row)

t=# select split_part('千葉県富津市新富２０−１　新日本製鐵株式会社　技術開発本部内',chr(12288),2);
     split_part
--------------------
 新日本製鐵株式会社
(1 row)
```