# Split string with split_part in Korean

Tags: sql, postgresql, split, cjk

Im referring to the following request:
[Split string with split_part in Asian language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47637493/split-string-with-split-part-in-asian-language)

It works for Japanese data, however, not for Korean addresses, at least in my case.

```
 select split_part('중국 베이징   하이디안 디스트릭트', chr(12288), 1)   
"중국 베이징   하이디안 디스트릭트"
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

you seem to use "simple" space here:

```
select split_part('중국 베이징   하이디안 디스트릭트', ' ', 1)
t-# ;
 split_part
------------
 중국
(1 row)
```

`chr(12288)` is "IDEOGRAPHIC space", while in your example yuo use ascii space `chr(32)`

Comment: thanks, you are right. However, I do not understand why I use ascii space in Korean addresses, but ideographic space in Japanese addresses.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ideographic_space "works" both for Korean and Japanese I suppose. I suppose you should ask why you have it for the person who put it there :)